# Touch events while the screen is being touched in Android

Tags: android, motionevent

I am trying to implement a basic virtual joystick in an Android custom View, using the following code.

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent e) {
            switch(e.getAction()){
                case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                    moving = true;
                    joystickVisibility = true;
                    joystickCoordinates[0] = (int) e.getX() - imageJoystick.getWidth() / 2;
                    joystickCoordinates[1] = (int) e.getY() - imageJoystick.getHeight() / 2;
                    joystickBaseCoordinates[0] = (int) e.getX() - imageJoystickBase.getWidth() / 2;
                    joystickBaseCoordinates[1] = (int) e.getY() - imageJoystickBase.getHeight() / 2;
                    break;
                case(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
                    joystickCoordinates[0] = (int) e.getX() - imageJoystick.getWidth() / 2;
                    joystickCoordinates[1] = (int) e.getY() - imageJoystick.getHeight() / 2;
                    if (joystickCoordinates[0] > joystickBaseCoordinates[0] + 50)
                        joystickCoordinates[0] = joystickBaseCoordinates[0] + 50;
                    if (joystickCoordinates[0] < joystickBaseCoordinates[0] - 50)
                        joystickCoordinates[0] = joystickBaseCoordinates[0] - 50;
                    if (joystickCoordinates[1] > joystickBaseCoordinates[1] + 50)
                        joystickCoordinates[1] = joystickBaseCoordinates[1] + 50;
                    if (joystickCoordinates[1] < joystickBaseCoordinates[1] - 50)
                        joystickCoordinates[1] = joystickBaseCoordinates[1] - 50;
                    break;
                case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                    moving = false;
                    joystickVisibility = false;
                    break;
                }
            move();
            postInvalidate();
            return true;
            }
    });
```

It is working except when the joystick is being held in one direction but not being moved.
I can't find any event that works while the screen is being touched.

Comment: Wanting the very same method for a button that "Streams Audio" whilst being touched, did you ever find a solution?